# Casting x.year from Datetime as a string

Tags: python, datetime, text, casting

I'm trying to have a program that writes the day, month and year from Datetime to a flat file. However it doesn't seem to let me cast the indivilual parts (day month year) as a string.

```
    # Setting Up the Variable:
    x = datetime.datetime.today()
    print(x.year,x.month,x.day,sep='')

    # Writing to file
    fo.write("350|")
    #working
    fo.write(x.year)
```

I run it and I recieve the following error:

```
File "main.py", line 408, in MTDReq
fo.write(x.year)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int**
```

I have tried casting it the normal way with "Year = str(x.year) but obviously this doesn't work and I'm all out of options, does anyone have any ideas?

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: why does `str(x.year)` not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fo.write(str(x.year))` has no reason not to work, though you should probably use `datetime.strftime('%Y')` instead.

It also looks like you're writing fields individually which is a bit odd, why not use a custom CSV dialect and write the output record by record through that?

Comment: Ahh I think my problem here was trying to cast it as a string first, then writing it to the file.. I was unaware you could cast it while writing!

I am only a beginner so I was just doing it the most simple way possible, this CSV Dialect you speak of does sound great, I'll look it up myself but do you have any sites/resources to recommend?

Comment: csv is a module from the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html by default it uses the comma as the separator (hence the name) but you can override that option when creating a writer or dictwriter.